# Creating Multiple textboxes dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am making a web application in which I pass a Int value from a servlet to next jsp page like this :

```
request.setAttribute("n",n);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/sharingfilesselection.jsp");  
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Now on the next page i.e sharingfilesselection.jsp I want that n textboxes are created dynamically each with a different id as i need to store the values of these textboxes in my database.

The N is obtained on next jsp page by this :

```
Object N=request.getAttribute("n");
```

How this can be done using javascript ?Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989741/dynamically-add-controls-javascript-asp-net-c-sharp i hope this helps you

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri I want that n textboxes to appear at same time.Not one by one.

Comment: it is just to give you an idea on how to do it. in your scenario you have to create textboxes in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using JSTL:

```html
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${n}">
    Input ${i}: <input type="text" name="txtDynamic_${i}" id="txtDynamic_${i}" />
    <br />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Here id of each textbox will be txtDynamic_1 ,txtDynamic2 and so on?

Comment: @user3509463 : Yes. You can give name whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your 
**.javascript**

```
<%String n=(String)request.getAttribute("n");%>
var n=<%=n%>;
for(var i=0;i<n;i++{
   $(".exac").append("<input type="text" id='textbox"+i+"'></input>");
    }
}
```

**.html**

```
<div class="exac">
</div>
```

Comment: Using scriptlets in bad. It is not recommended.

Comment: I agree wid u..just giving him a suggestion as Luiggi has already given a solution w.

Answer (score 1):

[Working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/2tsD7/)

> html

```
<div id="container"><input type="button" onclick="createTextBox(5)" value="create textbox">
```

JS

```
function createTextBox(n) {

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var textBox = document.createElement("input");

    textBox.setAttribute("id", "text_" + i);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(textBox);
}}
```